# OWASP dependency-check-maven: Why OSSIndex is called although <ossindexAnalyzerEnabled> is false?

Tags: maven, owasp, sonatype

We have several projects where we use the OWASP dependency-check-maven plugin. The plugin is defined in the build/plugins section; either with goal "check" or "aggregate". Latter in the parent pom for multi module projects.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <formats>HTML,JSON</formats>
        <cveValidForHours>168</cveValidForHours>
        <ossindexAnalyzerEnabled>false</ossindexAnalyzerEnabled> 
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>aggregate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In all we first ran in the problem that we couldn't access OSSIndex of Sonatype (we have no account there). We got this error (check is performed by Jenkins):

```
[ERROR] AnalysisException: OSS Index access forbidden
[ERROR] caused by TransportException: Unexpected response; status: 403
```

After some research we added `<ossindexAnalyzerEnabled>false</ossindexAnalyzerEnabled>` to our poms.
This solved the problem for all projects but the two multi module projects. Jenkins still received the above mentioned error.
Locally all runs smoothly.

We start the check with `mvn clean org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:aggregate` (or with "check" as goal).

**Why is the OSS Index still called by our multi module projects although it should not be called according to the configuration?**

===

In a first approach we defined the dependency-check-maven plugin for the multi module projects in a separate profile in the section reporting/plugins (same plugin configuration as above).
We started the check with `mvn site -Pcheck-dependencies -P!default`.

More strangely than now, the check of one multi module project didn't try to connect to OSS Index but the check of the other multi module project did.
After moving the plugin definition to the build/plugins section we got rid of this problem. But now both still tries to connect to OSSIndex.

Comment: Of course, I found the issue on my end. It was a little mess with different versions of the referenced parent pom in the individual modules.